# What is $n$ if $\frac{1+3+5 \cdots+ (2n-1)}{2+4+6+ \cdots 2n}=\frac{2017}{2018}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory

> Given that $\dfrac{1+3+5 \cdots+ (2n-1)}{2+4+6+ \cdots 2n}=\dfrac{2017}{2018}$, what is the value of $n$?

Okay this question seems pretty simple, but I really don't know how to do it. All I know is so far that for the denominator, $1+2+3+\ldots+n=1009$, and that I should somehow use $\frac{n(n+1)}2$. But I'm not so sure how. Also, for the numerator, I know that if you add $1$ to all the numbers, you result in the same expression in the denominator. But I'm not sure where to go from there. Can someone give me some advice, hints, or clues?

Comment: Please write up the question instead of making people click through.  Images cannot be searched.

Comment: I guess it is a `+`, not `=` in the numerator?

Comment: yeah its a + thanks. And I'll try to type it out next time sorry about that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You already know that $$\sum_{k=1}^n k=\frac{n(n+1)}2.$$ Therefore, $$\sum_{k=1}^n 2k=n(n+1),$$ $$\sum_{k=1}^n 2k-1=\sum_{k=1}^n 2k-\sum_{k=1}^n 1=n^2.$$ We can now rewrite the problem’s condition: $$\frac{n^2}{n(n+1)}=\frac{2017}{2018}\Rightarrow$$ $$\frac n{n+1}=\frac{2017}{2018}.$$ This is clearly only possible when $n=\boxed{2017}$. $\blacksquare$

Comment: @OP to see "clearly only possible", apply $\,f(x) = 1-x\,$ to the final equation to get $\,\dfrac{1}{n+1} = \dfrac{1}{2018}\ \ \ $

Comment: Ohhhhh. Yeah I see. Thanks for everything.

Comment: or cross-multiply from $\dfrac n{n+1}=\dfrac{2017}{2018}$ to get $2018n=2017n+2017$, and then subtract $2017n$ from both sides to get $n=2017$

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

Remember that a sum of $n$ consecutive terms of an arithmetic sequence is $${n\over 2}(a_1+a_n)$$

You have AS in numerator and denominator so you can apply this formula...

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do in these problems is try a few cases and try to guess the general formula from them. In the situation at hand, we have
$$1/2 = 1/2$$
$$(1 + 3)/(2 + 4) = 2/3$$
$$ (1 + 3  + 5)/(2 + 4 + 6) = 3/4$$
$$(1 + 3 + 5 + 7)/(2 + 4 + 6 + 8) = 4/5$$
It's natural to guess the overall pattern. The formulas in Bernard's answer will give a proof.

Comment: This is a multiple choice question on a mathleague test. All of the answers except the "other" choice is over 2000. So, the only thing I've realized is that if you use summations for the denominator there's no way a number over 2000 will give you a result of 1009. As in: 1+2+3...+n=1009.

Comment: @RyanKwok You'll likely get more optimized answer if you tell us the entire problem, including all the choices.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

The sum of the first $n$ odd numbers is $n^2$, the sum of the first $n$ even numbers is …

Comment: @Zarrax: You're right, two formulæ are too much (all the more so as the second is more or less obvious).